# Pandas, groupby manipulating columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'Col1': ['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b'], 'Col2': ['s','t','u','v','w','x','s','t','u','v']})


   id Col1 Col2
0   1   a   s
1   2   b   t
2   3   c   u
3   4   d   v
4   5   a   w
5   6   b   x
6   7   c   s
7   8   d   t
8   9   a   u
9   10  b   v
```

I want to get something like this

```
   id Col1 Col2
0   1   a   s
1   5   a   w
2   9   a   u
3   2   b   t
4   6   b   x
5   10  b   v
6   3   c   u
7   7   c   s
8   4   d   v
9   8   d   t
```

I have searched over stackoverflow with groupby keyword and i can't find a problem which is similar to mine.

Comment: `df.sort_values('Col1')`

Answer (score 2):

```
print( df.sort_values(['Col1', 'id', 'Col2'], ignore_index=True) )
```

Prints:

```
   id Col1 Col2
0   1    a    s
1   5    a    w
2   9    a    u
3   2    b    t
4   6    b    x
5  10    b    v
6   3    c    u
7   7    c    s
8   4    d    v
9   8    d    t
```